# Make or Makes for

Tags: grammar

Which is correct:

People with closed minds make terrible leaders?

OR

People with closed minds makes for terrible leaders?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*To make for* is an idiom with several different meanings. In the context of this question, the approximate meaning is 'to produce', 'to represent' or 'to constitute':

> Raw earthworms **make for** grim eating = Raw earthworms represent an unpleasant kind of food
>
> Dobermans **make for** great guard dogs = Dobermans have the qualities needed to make them great guard dogs
>
> Sowing camomile in your lawn **makes for** very fragrant picnicking = When you sow camomile in your lawn, the result can be aromatic picnics

*People with closed minds **makes** for terrible leaders* is incorrect because the wrong form of 'makes' is used (it doesn't agree in number with 'people'); *People with closed minds **make** for terrible leaders* is fine.

In the context of the kind of situation you asked about, as well as in the first two of my examples, 'make' and 'make for' are pretty much equivalent.

'Make for' is slightly more colloquial/conversational. It is also the form that works when you introduce a statement with a verb in the present progressive tense, as in my 'camomile' example.

Both Patrick T. Randolph and J_LV have answered your main point correctly.

Comment: If 'Dobermans make for great guard dogs' is correct then why isn't 'People with closed minds make for terrible leaders' correct?

Comment: Also could you explain when to use make for vs makes for?

Comment: *People with closed minds **makes** for terrible leaders* is incorrect because the wrong form of 'makes' is used (it doesn't agree in number with 'people'); *People with closed minds **make** for terrible leaders* is fine. In the context of the kind of situation you asked about, as well as in the first two of my examples, 'make' and 'make for' are pretty much equivalent. 'Make for' is slightly more colloquial/conversational. It is also the form that works when you introduce a statement with a verb in the present progressive tense, as in my 'camomile' example.

Comment: Erik, if you would add the contents of your last comment to your answer, it would really round it out. Plus, I would have an answer I can accept :)

Comment: As you wish...  :)

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is "People with closed minds make" because the subject verb agreement
is a plural + plural structure. Does that help?

"People with closed minds" = plural

"Make" = used for plural nouns; i.e., "People make ~."

"Makes" is for third person singular = he/she/it

Comment: What is wrong with this answer? It's clear and concise.

Comment: Someone seems to be on a 'downvoting' spree.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter. But one problem with this answer is that, while correcting the OPs sentences, it doesn't explain the difference between "make" and "make for".

Comment: ... For which reason I've now downvoted.

Answer (score -1):

The first one is correct assuming "xxxxx" contains a noun and that you're trying to go for something like:

> Narrow-minded people make terrible dads.

Comment: updated it to include the missing word.

Comment: It wasn't me....